# Rails 5 params with object having empty arrays as values are dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I'm having a problem when sending a controller params that look like this:

```
{ id: "1", stuff: {"A" => [], "B" => [], "C" => [], "D" => []} }
```

The method only sees `{ id: "1" }` and the entire `stuff` parameter is dropped.

This can be changed if there are any values in the arrays. But say there are values in all the arrays except for the key `"C"`, they will all be there besides `"C"` like:

```
{ id: "1", stuff: {"A" => ["1"], "B" => ["2", "3"], "D" => ["4"]} }
```

I'm falling into this problem upgrading from Rails 4.2.x -> 5.0.0
Any suggestions on what is happening here? I've seen a few articles/issues around [munging parameters](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13420), but I'm not sure if that's the issue because in their example table of how munging works is `{person: []}` becomes `{person: nil}`, where the person param isn't dropped completely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From @sgrif in the GH community:

> This is the expected behavior. There is no way to encode an empty
>   array using an HTML form (e.g. Content-Type: url-form-encoded). The
>   reason your tests passed in Rails 4.2 is because controller tests did
>   not encode their parameters, they simply passed the hash through
>   directly. In Rails 5 it encodes them. If your controller cares about
>   empty arrays, it's likely that you are dealing with JSON requests. You
>   can do that in your test with as: :json. If you're just dealing with
>   form input, you will never receive an empty array.

Adding `as: :json` didn't end up working for me, but adding `@request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'` at the beginning of the test did.

Comment: Thanks, that header tweak does the trick for me too. Do we have any clue why as: :json solution isn't working?

Comment: I didn't pry into that any further, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!